# Doc lib view formatting: accessing filetype icons

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am trying to get the file icons displayed in the standard view in the document libraries:

[image]

I want them to be displayed on a custom "file card" alongside the filename and a preview.

The SE article [linked here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278896/how-do-you-display-the-doc-icon-in-a-formatted-view) didn't help as they suggest using the Fabric Icons. But I want the original SharePoint icons.

**Edit:**
I added this code below to take care of different filetypes. Works like a charm.

```
"attributes": { "src": "='https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric-cdn-prod_20201207.001//assets/item-types/20/' + 
if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'docx'|| [$File_x0020_Type] == 'dotx'  || 
[$File_x0020_Type] == 'pptx' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'potx' || 
[$File_x0020_Type] == 'ppsx' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'xlsx'  || 
[$File_x0020_Type] == 'pdf' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'zip'||
 [$File_x0020_Type] == 'txt' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'folder', [$File_x0020_Type], if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'mp4' || 
[$File_x0020_Type] == 'mpg' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'avi', 'video', 
if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'jpg' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'gif' || 
[$File_x0020_Type] == 'png' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'png','photo', 
if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'json', 'code', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'eml' || 
[$File_x0020_Type] == 'msg', 'email', 'genericfile'))))) + '.svg'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `img` control to show the file type icon using JSON formatting.

You need to set the `src` property of img element based on `[$File_x0020_Type]`. In SharePoint online, default icon URLs are in below format:

**Example**: Word document Icon URL:

```
https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric-cdn-prod_20201207.001//assets/item-types/20/docx.svg
```

You can get this URL by inspecting the icons in document library view:

[image]

Similarly you can get the URLs for other file type icons & build JSON like:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "img",
   "attributes": {
      "src": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'png', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric-cdn-prod_20201207.001//assets/item-types/20/photo.svg', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'docx','https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric-cdn-prod_20201207.001//assets/item-types/20/docx.svg', ''))",
      "alt": "=[$File_x0020_Type]"
   },
   "style": {
      "width": "50%",
      "max-width": "50%"
   }
}
```

**Sample output**:

[image]

This is just an example, you can modify it based on the different file types (by adding more conditions in `src` attribute) & utilize it in view formatting JSON.

**Update**: Simplified version of above JSON:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "img",
   "attributes": {
      "src": "= 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric-cdn-prod_20201207.001//assets/item-types/20/' + if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'png', 'photo.svg', if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'docx', 'docx.svg', ''))",
      "alt": "=[$File_x0020_Type]"
   },
   "style": {
      "width": "50%",
      "max-width": "50%"
   }
}
```